# Browserify `crypto.createDecipher` "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length"

Tags: javascript, cryptography, browserify

I have a crypto code sample that works in Node, but when I try it in browserify, I get a "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length"

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

function encrypt(data, key, algorithm, encoding) {
    algorithm = algorithm || "aes256";
    encoding = encoding || "base64";
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);
    return cipher.update(data, "utf8", encoding) + cipher.final(encoding);
}

function decrypt(data, key, algorithm, encoding) {
    algorithm = algorithm || "aes256";
    encoding = encoding || "base64";
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key);
    return decipher.update(data, encoding, "utf8") + decipher.final("utf8");
}

var key = "this is a very secure key";
var data = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

var encryptedData = encrypt(data, key);
console.log("Encrypted: ", encryptedData);

var decryptedData = null;
try {
    decryptedData = decrypt(encryptedData, key);
    console.log("Decrypted: ", decryptedData);
} catch (ex) {
  console.log("Oops!", ex.stack);
}

if (data === decryptedData) {
  console.log("It worked!");
} else {
  console.log("Something went terribly wrong, my friend.");
}
```

Output from Node:

```
$ node crypto.js
Encrypted:  ClvTr5IWbgLHmgGQi81T6xtCR1RX4j5prSvFmtFr9+EXr5qKePKWcnu4tdFckh50
Decrypted:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
It worked!
```

Output from Browserify:

```
Encrypted:  ClvTr5IWbgLHmgGQi81T6xtCR1RX4j5prSvFmtFr9+E=F6+ainjylnJ7uLXRXJIedA==
Oops! RangeError: Invalid array length
```

A few interesting observations:

1. The encrypted output is different right after `Fr9+E` (about 43 chars in) leading me to think that the issue is in the encryption and not the decryption.
2. It works if I choose a smaller string for `data` such as "testing".

The entire code is on [RequireBin](http://requirebin.com/?gist=66e1baa0f206f9a184c9). Anything you can do to point me in the right direction to getting this solved would be appreciated.

#### Update

If I add the following line of code just before calling `decrypt` (i.e. decrypt Node's encrypted data) it works. Proving my point that the error lies in the encryptor.

`encryptedData = "ClvTr5IWbgLHmgGQi81T6xtCR1RX4j5prSvFmtFr9+EXr5qKePKWcnu4tdFckh50";`

#### Update 2

Setting the algorithm to `aes-256-ctr` will make my test pass in Browserify, but I'm still concerned that browserify-crypto's `aes256` yields different a different result than Node's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED!**

It turns out that this was an issue with Browserify's base64 encoding of the data. It was merged into master by the fine folks at Browserify (see https://github.com/crypto-browserify/browserify-aes/pull/23).